# Configure IIS for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, iis-7, administration

I am in dispair. I have no idea of how to configure an IIS for ASP.NET MVC. Basically any tutorial links are helpful, since i could not find good links on any search engine. I am completely new to any sort of administrative tasks. But i will ask more acurate questions, which i try to answer immediately, but there are errors because nothing works.

1.) Making an empty WebApp suitable for razor view engine (open f.e. /index.cshtml)?
* Create a Site which uses "ASP.NET v4.0" AppPool
* Create a WebApp underneath which inherits all Configurations from the Site
* Create a Bin Folder, copy System.Web.Razor.dll, System.Web.Mvc.dll into the Bin Folder
* Create a cshtml file, it should open.

2.) Adding ASP.NET Folders (for application startup, f.e.)?
* Just add App_Code, things like RouteConfig should will be automatically called and work

3.) Make the Page public (i totally cannot understand that part)?
* As authentication method use Pass-Trough-Authentication
* Make sure the IIS_IUSRS can read the Folder

Please help me, i dont know what i am missing or doing wrong.
BR
efkah

Comment: Your first section (#1) leads me to believe that you should find a basic tutorial on how to create an MVC project.  Just having the assemblies and a cshtml file will not create an MVC site.  You will need to code relevant controller/actions that tell the application where the views are and what data (if any) to send to that view. Also, you will need the proper tools (Visual Studio) to create and deploy an MVC app.  Here is a good starting place - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: the programming aint the problem, i just want to understand what to do with this god damn iis-7. do you really think that a cshtml wont run when the binaries are deployed? @Tommy

Comment: umm, yes, i do.  The binaries do not magically make IIS "run" cshtml files.

Comment: I understand the tutorial, i just dont understand how to deploy. Simply copying the Output of the deploy-functionality to a webapp folder doesn´t work. I don´t want to be unfriendly since you are the only one thats trying to help me @Tommy, but if you ever published a mvc app please tell me how you did it, or maybe ask your companies server administrators what to do?